# Android Shared Preference Still visible after Deleting File

Tags: android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

I am trying an application where I am using Shared Preference. When I delete the preference file from  **data/data/com.your.package.name/shared_prefs/mySharedPref.xml** manually using Android monitor, still the app is able to read the preference values.

I am assuming that some how the value is retained in main memory of the phone. Am I correct & what is the viable solution to clear shared preferences totally leaving no traces. But one thing I want to clear preference only if the file is wiped. **For this I need to check presence of file, Any other approach rather than checking with File class ?**

Comment: please clear your second question. In the end of your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think this code must work

```
 public static void clearAllPreference(Context context){
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove specific values: `SharedPreferences.Editor.remove()` followed by a commit()

To remove them all `SharedPreferences.Editor.clear()` followed by a commit()

**You use remove() to remove specific preferences, you use clear() to remove them all.**

Checkout official documentation on [SharedPreferences.Editor](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html).